# Append radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

How to append radio button using jquery or javascript to save into the databse?

I appended input types like text,textarea,checkbox,select with options.

My code is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
apnd
</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var htmldata='<div>Name<input type="text" name="cname[]">Mobile Number<input type="text"name="mob[]">Gender<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="M">Male<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="F">FemaleAddress<textarea name="address[]"></textarea><input type="button" class="remove_field" value="remove"></div>';
$('.add_field').click(function(){
$('.wrapper').append(htmldata); 
});
$('.wrapper').on('click','.remove_field',function(){
$(this).parent('div').remove(); 
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
    Name<input type="text" name="cname[]">
    Mobile Number<input type="text" name="mob[]">
    Gender<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="M">Male
          <input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="F">Female
    Address<textarea name="address[]"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="add_field" value="Add">
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

using php I want to save the values to database.

```
$name=sc_sql_injection($_POST['cname']);
        $mobile=sc_sql_injection($_POST['mob']);
        $gender=sc_sql_injection($_POST['gender']);
        $address=sc_sql_injection($_POST['address']);
        $count=count($_POST['cname']);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
            $sql="insert into t2(name,mobile,gender,address) values('$name[$i]','$mobile[$i]','$gender[$i]','$address[$i]')";
            sc_exec_sql($sql,$con);
   }
```

**Update**
[image]

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: This is sample code.

Comment: Only a few people know but Marc B actually set up a bot that comments about SQL injection vulnerability in questions without mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: You never really describe the problem here - what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Please check my update,  my problem is only one radio button is getting checked.

Comment: @vijaykumar Honestly, I'm not familiar with phps, but if out of all of those radio buttons only one is able to be chosen, the name attribute is the same for all of them. You want to make them the same for the male and female button, but not for each different field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append radio button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>
    apnd
    </title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var i=1;
    $('.add_field').click(function(){
    var htmldata='<div>Name<input type="text" name="cname[]">Mobile Number<input type="text"name="mob[]"> Gender<input type="radio" name="gender['+i+']" value="M">Male<input type="radio" name="gender['+i+']" value="F">Female Address<textarea name="address[]"></textarea><input type="button" class="remove_field" value="remove"></div>';
            i++;
    $('.wrapper').append(htmldata); 
    });
    $('.wrapper').on('click','.remove_field',function(){
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
    i--;
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        Name<input type="text" name="cname[]">
        Mobile Number<input type="text" name="mob[]">
        Gender<input type="radio" name="gender[0]" value="M">Male
              <input type="radio" name="gender[0]" value="F">Female
        Address<textarea name="address[]"></textarea>
        <input type="button" class="add_field" value="Add">
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Save">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
$('.add_field').click(function(){
var htmldata='<div>Name<input type="text" name="cname[]">Mobile Number<input type="text"name="mob[]"> Gender<input type="radio" name="gender['+i+']" value="M">Male<input type="radio" name="gender['+i+']" value="F">Female Address<textarea name="address[]"></textarea><input type="button" class="remove_field" value="remove"></div>';
  i++;
$('.wrapper').append(htmldata); 
});
$('.wrapper').on('click','.remove_field',function(){
$(this).parent('div').remove(); 
i--;
});
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
 Name<input type="text" name="cname[]">
 Mobile Number<input type="text" name="mob[]">
 Gender<input type="radio" name="gender[0]" value="M">Male
       <input type="radio" name="gender[0]" value="F">Female
 Address<textarea name="address[]"></textarea>
 <input type="button" class="add_field" value="Add">
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
  </html>
```